# Angular ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush not triggering on Input-Change

Tags: angular

For hopefully finally understanding all the Angular ChangeDetection-things (sorry, I know there are thousands of pretty good articles / tuts out there), I created the following Stackblitz, where a OnPush-Component does **not** update on an input change: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qhqopi.

Angular states, that components always update on input-change, but as far as I know, they only do, if the input is set via binding (shown in my Stackblitz, too).

Now I want to know: am I correct with my assumption? And: can my `TestPushSaveComponent`

```
template: <div>Input: {{ (data$ | async)?.value ?? '-' }}</div>

@Component({
  selector: 'test-push-save',
  templateUrl: './test-save.component.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class TestPushSaveComponent {
  get data(): any {
    return this.data$.value;
  }
  @Input() set data(value: any) {
    this.data$.next(value);
    this.dataChange.emit(value);
  }
  @Output() dataChange = new EventEmitter<any>();
  data$ = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
}
```

be used as a best practice for `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`? I was told to not use `|async` for input properties, since the change detection gets triggered itself. But since I cannot know how someone uses my component (set property via binding or code) I guess this is the best solution for all circumstances?

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is indeed correct. Angular's `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` only marks the component for check if either one of its inputs is updated via binding, or if the component itself (or one of its children) dispatches an event.

What you are doing in your example - pushing a value to your component from outside - is pretty much considered a bad practice and should be avoided. If you really want to support this use case, consider just marking your component for check manually instead of abusing the `| async` pipe.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'test-push-save',
  templateUrl: './test-save.component.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class TestPushSaveComponent {
  @Input() set data(value: any) {
    this._data = value;
    this.cdr.markForCheck();
  }
  get data(): any {
    return this._data;
  }
  private _data:any;

  constructor(private readonly cdr:ChangeDetectorRef) {}
}
```

See the [working StackBlitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hesdmd?file=src/test/test-save.component.html).

Comment: Since I need to support this use case, why would you call using the async pipe an abuse? For me it seams like a pretty clean, robust solution. Are there any disadvantages I don't see? This way I do not need to call cdr on many places in my components (e.g. after my components refresh method was called, changing multiply of it's properties.

Comment: In your example you are subscribing to your observable at exactly one point. If you had multiple, you'd either have to introduce an ng-container or subscribe at multiple levels. That's not really clean if it is avoidable. In my example, if you have something like a refresh method, the component will also be marked for check - can't really see any benefit in using an observable abstraction for that. I'm calling it an 'abuse' because all you're doing is using the async pipe for change detection, that's like using spring boot to print hello world.

Comment: Ok, got your point. But it seams more like an opinion - or are there any caveats for my solution? I think it's a pretty robust setup to always insure the latest value for my view via Async-Pipe

Comment: As soon as you have 2 working solutions, which one you choose is always an opinion ;) This is the intended API for handling custom ChangeDetection. Using the async pipe does work but you're adding the overhead of wrapping and unwrapping the value into a semantically meaningless observable. That is at the very least not a good design choice.

Comment: Hope I'm not annoying you with my questions but really want to understand it. If this use-case is an abuse of the async pipe, what is it made for? I'm using it for showing an observable property in the frontend.

Comment: No worries, you're not! :) 
The async pipe itself is made for exactly that purpose - displaying values wrapped in an observable on your template. In itself, this is not bad - rather contrary, it's a pretty good pattern. It's the fact that you only create the observable to trigger ChangeDetection and that this observable has no other meaning what makes this a bad practice. Try to imagine what happens if you have 10 inputs that you want to display in 10 places in your template - this blows up your template unnecessarily without providing any benefits that observables are meant for.

Comment: Ah, ok! Now I got your point! The demo-case is actually pretty simplified! It's a quite complex scenario that suits the async pipe just well. Thank you for clarification and your recommendations!